# Проверка существования тега

Tags: php, keyword, mysql

Всем привет, появилась необходимость, допилить добавление тегов к блогу. И вот идея следующая, если пришёл пост['keywords'], то разбиваем его (через запятые). Далее, вытаскиваем теги из бд, и сверями новые теги с ними, если есть такие же, то ничего не делаем, если нет, то добавляем в бд название тега.

**Вот код:**

```
// Допустим это теги которые пришли с $_GET
$text = "text1,text2,text3,программирование,text5,text6,text7";
// Разобьём 
$data = explode(",", $text);
// Возьмём теги из БД
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM keywords") or die("Error #345738");
// есть ли они вообще
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        // занесём все теги из бд в массив
        $row[] = $result;
    }
    // Переберём массив row 
    foreach ($row as $name) {
        // переберём входящий массив $_GET
        foreach ($data as $postname) {
            // если нет в бд такого массива, занесём его туда
            if (!$name == $postname) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO keywords (name) VALUES ('" . $postname . "')");
            }
        }
    }        
} else {
}
```

проблема в том, что ничего не происходит, в бд есть уже пару тегов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно существенно сократить код, используя такие функции как:
array_intersect
[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php)
и их модификации.
Помимо этого забудьте про семейство функций mysql_* - скоро они исчезнут из PHP, используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).
А проблема непосредственно в том, что `$name` это строка, а `$postname` это массив, сравнивать их и есть ошибка.